# how to post JSON data to web service using Apache Wink RestClient?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, apache-wink

I'm trying to test a JAX-RS by doing a POST of JSON data from Java.

I'm using Apache Wink 1.0, and the Apache Wink RestClient.  The [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/61-getting-started-with-apache-wink-client.html) say this is how you do a POST ...

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
Resource resource = client.resource("http://services.co");
String response = resource.contentType("text/plain").accept("text/plain").post(String.class, "foo");
```

... but what changes do I make to POST JSON data?

I tried this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("abc", 123);

RestClient client = new RestClient();
Resource resource = client.resource("http://services.co");
JSONObject response = resource.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(JSONObject.class, json);
```

... but I on POST I get an exception with this error: "No writer for type class net.sf.json.JSONObject and media type application/json".

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Rob

Comment: Your code looks pretty much on point except that I would expect the `.post` to be with `String.class`, not `JSONObject.class`.

Comment: Thanks, changed to 'String response = resource.content ... post(String.class, json)' and now the client is happy.  However, I have a new server problem, I'm adding a new question -- please help! :) Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538342/whats-wrong-with-my-simple-json-jax-rs-web-service

Comment: @Perception - Please post your comment as an answer, and I'll mark it correct!

Comment: Thanks -- please look at my new question too, I'm rather stuck.

Comment: Dead link to docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks pretty much correct except that I would expect the post to be done with a String entity. As such you may want to change:

```
JSONObject response = resource.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(JSONObject.class, json);
```

To:

```
String response = resource.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(String.class, json);
```